# Karma - Access variables from config file

Tags: karma-runner

Is there a way, to access config values from the karma.config.js file inside a test? I want to set some values there for different environments.

Comment: Never heard about it but can you be more precise about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd also like to know if this is possible. I find myself retyping a lot of values in different configs and would like to be able to read in shared values from a shared file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can access the configuration by using the __karma__ object:

```
__karma__.config
```

Please note that in order to help typescript to 'see' this object you have to declare it first:

```
// There is no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Declare it here as any
declare const __karma__: any;
```